# Missing database when reinstalling TFS: Tfs_Analysis

Tags: sql, tfs

I am trying to install TFS 2013 on a server that previously had TFS 2015 installed, then removed.

When the process runs, there are a number of databases it can find, that need to be removed. I have removed these, but it is saying there is still one database: `Tfs_Analysis`.

I have looked in the server and I cannot see the database in the list of databases. I have full permissions on the server, so it is not a case of it being there and I cannot see it.

What is really confusing me is that SQL Server will allow me to create a database with the same name and remove it.

I have restarted the SQL Services and have also restarted the server. Can anyone suggest what I am missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you connect to the database from SQL Management Studio, choose Analysis Services as the server type

[image: Analysis DB]

Now you should see Tfs_Analysis under the list of databases and you can delete it so the TFS 2013 setup doesn't give you any trouble

[image: Delete]